# How can I pass the argument from module to unittest module?

Tags: python

I have 2 files:

test_1.py:

```
import unittest

class TestMe(unittest.TestCase):

   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
       cls.name = "test"
       cls.password = "1234"

   def test_upper(self):
       self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

   def test_user_pass(self):
       print(self.name)
       print(self.password)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test_2.py:

```
import unittest
import test_1
import sys

a = sys.argv

if a[1] == '2':
    suite=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test_1)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

I want to pass the argument to test_1(unittes module) but I need this argument to setUpClass.
How can I do that?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. I'm not sure what you want to do, but you may want to use `TestLoader().discover(<path_in_which_your_test_files_are>, pattern=<string_that_describes_what_tests_are>)`. Pattern example : `"test_*.py"`. -- Here, you're trying to load the file, instead of the class. You should import the class as in `from test_1 import TestMe`, and do `loadTestsFromModule(TestMe)`.

Comment: @IMCoins I just need the argument that I pass in the file test_1.py. For example if I will try to run my code via terminal I mean python3 test_2.py 2 so I need the argument 2 in the file test_1.py but I need him in my setUpClass()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several of doing this.

The easiest choice would be to include the following in all your scripts.

```py
import sys
some_arg = sys.argv[1]
```

You will be able to access the argument you put into your main in every file you go after.

The second option would be to use this as a function, typically, you could do...

```py
def build_test_class(arg):
    Class TestMe(unittest.TestCase):
        ... do stuff ...

    return TestMe
```

Here, you would have your argument to use with your class.

But there **must be** another way of doing what you're trying to do. I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's work I will try to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

test_1.py:

```
import unittest
from test_2 import b


class TestMe(unittest.TestCase):

    e = b

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.name = "test"
        cls.password = "1234"
        cls.parameter = cls.e

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_user_pass(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.password)
        print(self.parameter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test_2.py:

```
import unittest
import test_1
import sys

a = sys.argv
b = ""

if a[1] == '2':
    b = a[1]
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test_1)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

I hope this will help you.